# How can I use OpenGL to create Canadian Flag Red Maple Leaf

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

I've this image
[image: canadian-flag-maple-leaf]
How can i scripting using Dev C/C++ with OpenGL to make that above image?

I just coding using this below scripts but its different [image: result]

Here's my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
    
void display() {
    
    glClearColor(0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //glTranslatef(0.5, 0, 0);
    //glScalef(0.5, 0.5, 0);
    //glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //UnifoliÃ© also known as Maple Leaf
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.8, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(-0.25, -0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.1, -0.2);
    glVertex2f(-0.35, -0.2);
    glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.25, 0.2);
    glVertex2f(-0.35, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.2);
    glVertex2f(0.35, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.25, 0.2);
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.2, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(0.35, -0.2);
    glVertex2f(0.1, -0.2);
    glVertex2f(0.25, -0.5);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0.00, 0.00);
    glVertex2f(0.00, 0.90);
    glVertex2f(-0.08, 0.70);
    glVertex2f(-0.12, 0.66);
    glVertex2f(-0.16, 0.66);
    glVertex2f(-0.20, 0.68);
    glVertex2f(-0.24, 0.74);
    glVertex2f(-0.22, 0.64);
    glVertex2f(-0.22, 0.62);
    glVertex2f(-0.24, 0.56);
    glVertex2f(-0.26, 0.54);
    glVertex2f(-0.30, 0.54);
    glVertex2f(-0.34, 0.56);
    glVertex2f(-0.36, 0.60);
    glVertex2f(-0.36, 0.56);
    glVertex2f(-0.38, 0.54);
    glVertex2f(-0.40, 0.54);
    glVertex2f(-0.42, 0.54);
    glVertex2f(-0.56, 0.60);
    glVertex2f(-0.52, 0.54);
    glVertex2f(-0.50, 0.50);
    glVertex2f(-0.48, 0.44);
    glVertex2f(-0.48, 0.42);
    glVertex2f(-0.50, 0.38);
    glVertex2f(-0.54, 0.34);
    glVertex2f(-0.48, 0.32);
    glVertex2f(-0.44, 0.28);
    glVertex2f(-0.42, 0.22);
    glVertex2f(-0.42, 0.20);
    glVertex2f(-0.44, 0.16);
    glVertex2f(-0.46, 0.16); //this 1st
    glVertex2f(-0.52, 0.18);
    glVertex2f(-0.54, 0.24);
    glVertex2f(-0.54, 0.20);
    glVertex2f(-0.56, 0.16);
    glVertex2f(-0.60, 0.14);
    glVertex2f(-0.62, 0.14);
    glVertex2f(-0.70, 0.16);
    glVertex2f(-0.76, 0.20);
    glVertex2f(-0.78, 0.24);
    glVertex2f(-0.76, 0.18);
    glVertex2f(-0.74, 0.14);
    glVertex2f(-0.70, 0.08);
    glVertex2f(-0.68, 0.06);
    glVertex2f(-0.66, 0.02);
    glVertex2f(-0.66, 0.00);
    glVertex2f(-0.68, -0.04);
    glVertex2f(-0.64, -0.02);
    glVertex2f(-0.62, -0.02);
    glVertex2f(-0.56, -0.04);
    glVertex2f(-0.52, -0.08);
    glVertex2f(-0.48, -0.16);
    glVertex2f(-0.48, -0.20);
    glVertex2f(-0.50, -0.26);
    glVertex2f(-0.52, -0.30);
    glVertex2f(-0.58, -0.34);
    glVertex2f(-0.42, -0.32);
    glVertex2f(-0.30, -0.28);
    glVertex2f(-0.18, -0.22);
    glVertex2f(-0.10, -0.20);
    glVertex2f(0.00, -0.22);
    glVertex2f(0.10, -0.20);
    glVertex2f(0.18, -0.22);
    glVertex2f(0.30, -0.28);
    glVertex2f(0.42, -0.32);
    glVertex2f(0.58, -0.34);
    glVertex2f(0.52, -0.30);
    glVertex2f(0.50, -0.26);
    glVertex2f(0.48, -0.20);
    glVertex2f(0.48, -0.16);
    glVertex2f(0.52, -0.08);
    glVertex2f(0.56, -0.04);
    glVertex2f(0.62, -0.02);
    glVertex2f(0.64, -0.02);
    glVertex2f(0.68, -0.04);
    glVertex2f(0.66, 0.00);
    glVertex2f(0.66, 0.02);
    glVertex2f(0.68, 0.06);
    glVertex2f(0.70, 0.08);
    glVertex2f(0.74, 0.14);
    glVertex2f(0.76, 0.18);
    glVertex2f(0.78, 0.24);
    glVertex2f(0.76, 0.20);
    glVertex2f(0.70, 0.16);
    glVertex2f(0.62, 0.14);
    glVertex2f(0.60, 0.14);
    glVertex2f(0.56, 0.16);
    glVertex2f(0.54, 0.20);
    glVertex2f(0.54, 0.24);
    glVertex2f(0.52, 0.18);
    glVertex2f(0.46, 0.16);
    glVertex2f(0.44, 0.16);
    glVertex2f(0.42, 0.20);
    glVertex2f(0.42, 0.22);
    glVertex2f(0.44, 0.28);
    glVertex2f(0.48, 0.32);
    glVertex2f(0.54, 0.34);
    glVertex2f(0.50, 0.38);
    glVertex2f(0.48, 0.42);
    glVertex2f(0.48, 0.44);
    glVertex2f(0.50, 0.50);
    glVertex2f(0.52, 0.54);
    glVertex2f(0.56, 0.60);
    glVertex2f(0.42, 0.54);
    glVertex2f(0.40, 0.54);
    glVertex2f(0.38, 0.54);
    glVertex2f(0.36, 0.56);
    glVertex2f(0.36, 0.60);
    glVertex2f(0.34, 0.56);
    glVertex2f(0.30, 0.54);
    glVertex2f(0.26, 0.54);
    glVertex2f(0.24, 0.56);
    glVertex2f(0.22, 0.62);
    glVertex2f(0.22, 0.64);
    glVertex2f(0.24, 0.74);
    glVertex2f(0.20, 0.68);
    glVertex2f(0.16, 0.66);
    glVertex2f(0.12, 0.66);
    glVertex2f(0.08, 0.70);
    glVertex2f(0.00, 0.90);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
    
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
    glutCreateWindow("Maple Leaf");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure your vertices are correct? Where did you get them from?

Comment: It's a better looking maple leaf than the stylised emblem you wanted but needs rotating. Presumably you found this and want to make it work for you. I notice that `glRotatef` has been commented out.